# MVC3 Controller.Redirect(string)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a private function like this in my controller.

```
private UserDetails GetUserDetails(int userid)
{
    ...
    if (some condition check is false)
        Redirect("some other page in a different subdomain");

    return userDetails;
}
```

If the condition fails, Redirect statement is executed, but the execution doesn't stop. userDetails is returned to the calling function. There is no redirect to some other page.

How can I force the redirect?

Comment: Why not pass null back if it fails and have your View handle or ignore the null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect returns a result - you're meant to use it from within an Action method as follows:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() 
{
    if (check is false) 
    {
        return Redirect("other url");
    }
    // this code won't get executed after redirect
}
```

It looks like you should return null from the function you posted above, then check for null and `return Redirect("...")` if GetUserDetails returned null.

Answer (score 1):

There are situations where you cannot redirect, although I am uncertain of what the stipulation is for the whole set of them. One way to get around that is to return a string to the view and have javascript do `window.location(url)` to force the redirect.